# Customer contacts API end point - Netsuite

Tags: rest, api, netsuite

Where I can find a list of API endpoints to Oracle Netsuite ? I am looking for the **customer contacts** end point in particular.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The NetSuite SOAP API is called SuiteTalk.  See: https://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/resources/suitetalk-documentation.shtml

Comment: @Brian, Thanks ! Also Is there a REST API system available ?

Comment: Look in the NetSuite Help Center for the topic: _SuiteTalk REST Web Services (Beta) Overview and Setup_. This just came out with NetSuite Release 2019.2 but as it says it is Beta and subject to change and not fully fleshed out. You can also write your own restlets to do the work.